# Simulate a click on admob (Android)

Tags: android, admob

I want to integrate native ads from adMob, the google solution for integrating ads ito app. However I cannot use them in a "normal" way because of the nature of my app.

The ad in my app cannot be clicked, and when my user execute a specific action, I want the ad to react as if it's been clicked (openning the ad and all). I've been reading the adMob documentation but seen no ways to do that. Is there a way to make the ad react has if it has been clicked?

Comment: this is more than likely against the terms of service of your android, and/or admob license(s)

Comment: [case and point](https://support.google.com/admob/answer/2753860?hl=en#invalid): `"Publishers may not click their own ads or use any means to inflate impressions and/or clicks artificially"`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No you can't do that. Don't try if you don't want to be banned. You can test your ads by using `AdRequest.Builder.addTestDevice`.

"It is against AdMob policy to use live ads during development, and doing so could cause the suspension of your AdMob account. For more information, review the AdMob policies and learn more about invalid activity" ([docs](https://developers.google.com/admob/android/quick-start)).

Comment: That's not for test, but because of the nature of my app. Guess I'm not using adMob then.

Comment: You won't be using any ad network. They will all ban you because subverting the process behind a user clicking on an ad undermines the whole ad monetary ecosystem. Ie it's bad for business.

Answer (score 0):

But if the ad in your app can not be clicked, then how does it work? Click is an essential metric in different models, that estimate the performance. Really interested does it work in your app? BTW seems like you can have difficulties with the majority of ad networks.

Comment: That's a fact, my app cannot use most of ad network using rtb or such. Still searching a network we can work with. The app im working on is called Swiper(only in France for now), its purpose is to serve ads on the user's lockscreen in a tinder-like way (ad can be swiped left or right depending on the user's taste). Thus I can't let user click on the ad since I need them to swipe it.

Comment: Take a look at StartApp& The have cool native ads and video& Might work for you I suppose